# Ruby - extract info from JSON with variable loop iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a JSON response which is stored as a string in "BQresponse"

```
{"kind":"bigquery#queryResponse", "schema":{"fields":[{"name":"Revenue", "type":"INTEGER", "mode":"NULLABLE"}, {"name":"Country", "type":"STRING", "mode":"NULLABLE"}]}, "jobReference":{"projectId":"curious-idea-532", "jobId":"job_S5rTcY2vwEu-amtrxb8NRPWiynU"}, "totalRows":"3", "rows":[{"f":[{"v":"100"}, {"v":"Ireland"}]}, {"f":[{"v":"200"}, {"v":"Netherlands"}]}, {"f":[{"v":"50"}, {"v":"Singapore"}]}], "totalBytesProcessed":"0", "jobComplete":true, "cacheHit":true}
```

I am trying to convert this into a two line response (for later export to CSV), looking exactly like this:

```
Country||Sum of Revenue|,Ireland,Netherlands,Singapore
Revenue,100,200,50
```

So far, I've extracted the first parts, like so:

```
puts BQresponse[/#{D1_mark1}(.*?)#{D1_mark2}/m, 1]+"||"+BQresponse[/#{M1_mark1}(.*?)#{M1_mark2}/m, 1]
```

Next I need to extract "Ireland,Netherlands,Singapore". However I cannot use the same approach as I have done above as there may be more or less values as the string is updated (maybe only 2 or 5 countries).

The string included a part that says "totalRows":"3"," - this 3 is the number of expected countries and I suppose could be used in a loop/for-each of some sort. But I'm not sure how to best approach this.

The number values on the second line face the exact same issue (each country has a number).  The "Revenue" on the second line is simply a repeat of "Revenue" on the first line, with "Sum_of_" removed.

Appreciate suggestions on what direction to head in.

Also, this is a valid JSON, if I'm completely off track and it would be easier to convert this string into a JSON first, that's okay too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an awesome gem for this, `json2csv` [here](https://github.com/korczis/json2csv) that I've had to use before.

To try it out, I'd save down a sample JSON response into a file called `sample.json` and then in your terminal you can run:

`json2csv convert sample.json`